# Lombok 1.18.2 does not work with maven and jdk 10

Tags: java, maven, lombok, java-10

Lombok is not creating the getters/setters when i try to compile my Java Projekt under JDK 10.

The class that uses Lombok annotations.

```
package com.testcompany.data;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class DataInfo {
    private Map<String,String> metadata = new HashMap<>();
    private String extractedString;
}
```

Usage of the Lombok annotated class

```
String test = dataInfo.getExtractedString();
```

I am using the following versions to compile my sources to java 10:

- maven (3.5.4)
- maven-compiler-plugin 3.8.0
- Java 10 (subversion 2)
- Lombok 1.18.2

pom.xml
in the dependency section

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>${lombok.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and in the maven-compiler-plugin section

```
<annotationProcessorPaths>
    <path>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
    </path>
</annotationProcessorPaths>
```

when I compile via mvn install i get the following error:

```
MemberRegistration.java:[50,36] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getExtractedString()
  location: variable dataInfo of type com.testcompany.data.DataInfo
```

Is there anything i need to do different when using jdk 10?

Comment: Isn't there an annotation `@Getters` needed?

Comment: No, from their documentation: `@Data is a convenient shortcut annotation that bundles the features of @ToString, @EqualsAndHashCode, @Getter / @Setter and @RequiredArgsConstructor together`

Comment: @Shannon true, `@Data` is sufficient and I can confirm with your dependency and ....
`<build><plugins><plugin><groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId><artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId><version>3.8.0</version><configuration><release>10</release><annotationProcessorPaths><path><groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId><artifactId>lombok</artifactId><version>1.18.2</version></path></annotationProcessorPaths></configuration></plugin></plugins></build>`, the maven build succeeds.

Comment: try a rebuild `mvn clean package`, also take a look to [this issue](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1572)

Comment: @Shannon are you using a `module-info.java`(module path) since that's what I didn't give it a try with?

Comment: i do not have a module-info.java - is it necessary? btw: whenyou say the build succeeds, does it mean that the getter/setters are created and can be used?

Comment: @Shannon Of course, I meant I was able to reuse getters for the `DataInfo` object. But that is when I do not have `module-info.java` in my project, including which Lombok is going crazy I believe. :P

Comment: @nullpointer, as far as i understand, you have the same configuration that I have, but your project works. I could post my test example project (maybe I will upload it somehow)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to all! 
The main problem was, that I used the compiler Argument "**-proc:none**" which means "compilation takes place without annotation processing...". So I removed this Argument. Beside of this, it is also recommended, to use the following compiler arguments (see **compilerArgs** section):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>10</source>                                                
    <target>10</target>                                                
    <release>10</release>                                              
    <executable>javac10</executable>
    <fork>false</fork>                            
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <!-- see https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/985#issuecomment-356135454 -->
    <compilerArgs>
        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
    </compilerArgs>
    <annotationProcessorPaths>
      <path>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.2</version>
      </path>
    </annotationProcessorPaths>
    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
  </configuration>
  <dependencies>                                                         
    <dependency>                                                       
      <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>                                 
      <artifactId>asm</artifactId>                                   
      <version>6.2</version>
    </dependency>                                                      
  </dependencies>
  </plugin>
<plugin>
```